# How to select NOT NULL columns from DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I've got a script I'm using against a DB2 database, and I'd like it to be able to check that all required values are present prior to trying an `INSERT`-- so I'd like to select a list of the `not null` columns from the table I'm about to insert into. Since the table definition may change I'd like to do this rather than using a static list so the script won't break if there's a new `not null` column added.

Is there a way to get these values from a DB2 query, maybe against `syscat`?

```
VERSIONNUMBER VERSIONTIMESTAMP    AUTHID    VERSIONBUILDLEVEL
-------------------------------------------------------
10010400    2016-12-03 16:46:01.509317  ADMIN   s140509
```

Comment: Is this DB2 LUW or z/OS or OS/400 ?

Comment: Looks like DB2 for LUW, 10.1 fp 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on LUW you can use the view `syscat.columns`:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html

For a certain table:

```
select colname 
from syscat.columns 
where tabschema = 'DB2INST1' 
  and tabname = 'STAFF' 
  and nulls = 'N' 
order by colno;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries SQL Reference
V5R3](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v5r3/en_US/rbafzmst.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A6863%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%5D)  documents, the `SYSCOLUMNS` view contains an `IS_NULLABLE` column.

[DB2 for z/OS 10](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsyscolumnstable.html) has a `NULLS` column that indicates if a column is nullable in `SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS` table

Potentially, [`SYSCAT.COLUMNS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24525868/1595565) may have the `IS_NULLABLE` or `NULLS` column.

I'm not a DB2 expert, so this may or may not be applicable to your system.